# Using jQuery to countdown from 90 seconds beginning on the click of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I was wondering if anyone can help me. I am trying to create a simple card game using html css and javascript. It has a 90 second timer which I want to start counting down on the first click of the card.

Any ideas how to do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: In order to find the help you require faster, It is advisable that you include what you have tried. This should help guide you https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a function after 90 seconds then

```js
element.onclick = function () {
    setTimeout(myFunctionAfter90Secs, 90 * 1000);
};
```

And you would define `element` to be the element that's clicked on (use a `querySelector`) and define your `myFunctionAfter90Secs`

If you want to display a timer then:
Html:

```html
<div id="timer"></div>
<div id="card"></div>
<script>
    var timer = document.querySelector("#timer");
    var card = document.querySelector("#card");
    var initialSeconds = 90;
    card.onclick = function () {
        var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (initialSeconds > -1) {
                timer.innerHTML = initialSeconds;
                initialSeconds--;
            }
            else {
                clearInterval(myInterval);
            }
        }, 1 * 1000);
    };
</script>
```

This will make sure your timer updates every second until it hits 0, then the reset should clear your interval but feel free to tweak the code to fix it